# How to apply 2 filters to the same column based on a boolean paramater in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services

Good Morning, I've a table on my report that has the total_available of inventory stock which needs to be filtered based on the user selection  by using a Boolean parameter

[image]

I've selected the column that has the quantities from 0 to 1000 and then Tablix properties , Filters and I've tried with multiple expressions but I cannot get it to work.

What needs to have is the following , if the Boolean parameter is true then it needs to apply a filter to show all quantities greater than 0 , if false it needs to show all quantities less than 10.

Below is the 10th expression that I've tried:

```
=IIF(Parameters!LowInventory.Value = true,Fields!Total_Available.Value,Fields!Total_Available.Value)

=IIF(Parameters!LowInventory.Value = false,Fields!Total_Available.Value,Fields!Total_Available.Value)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are there negative values to account for? Otherwise, you could just use less than 10.  I would suggest taking a look at [this link](https://kirkbarrett.wordpress.com/2013/11/29/filtering-datasets-using-a-boolean-report-parameter-to-determine-in-value-set/) for more help.  You'll need to `CBool` the "true" or "false" to compare correctly. Also, your expressions seem to set the value the same regardless of the evaluation.  `=IIF([condition], [TrueResult], [FalseResult])`.

Answer (score 1):

SSRS Filters don't have an OR - all of the conditions for all filters would need to be met for a record.

I think it would be easiest to combine the logic into one expression like:

```
=IIF(Parameters!LowInventory.Value = True  AND Fields!Total_Available.Value < 10, 1,
 IIF(Parameters!LowInventory.Value = False AND Fields!Total_Available.Value >  0, 1, 0))
```

Then change the type from TEXT to INTEGER and the Value to 1.

For reference: 
[technet.microsoft.com](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/33366.ssrs-tips-implementing-or-based-logic-for-dataset-filters.aspx)

I try to avoid using Boolean logic - there are some properties and expressions that don't work evaluate them correctly.